# No se como funciona el comando do while

Tags: c

Veran, me tope con un programa "sumahasta" el típico que le das 2 y el resultado es 3 o le das 4 y te retorna 10, nada raro, el tema es que un compañero la hizo hace años y ahora la veo y no entiendo como funciona aquí el do con el `while`, no logro captarlo, aquí les paso el código completo así lo ven.Desde ya muchas gracias.

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*Función que toma un N, declaro 2 contadores una comparándolo con N, y otro que se encargue de ir sumando esos i */

int suma_hasta(int N) {
    int i = 0;
    int x = 0;

    while (i<=N){
        x = x + i;
        i++;
    }
    return x; 
}

int main() {
    int n = 0;

    do{   
        printf("Ingrese un valor:\n");
        scanf("%d", &n);

        if (n < 0)
            printf("El valor no puede ser negativo,ingrese un nuevo valor\n");
        }

    }while(n < 0);

    printf("La suma hasta %d es %d \n", n, suma_hasta(n));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

el `do - while` que comentas en este programa solo esta repitiendo lo siguiente:

- imprime mensaje de "ingrese un valor"
- espera al ingreso del valor
- si el valor es inferior a 0, (o esa, se espera un numero positivo) se
  muestra un mensaje de error.

En resumen, el bucle solo esta leyendo un dato y esperando a que dicho dato sea valido. Es un `validador`.

Answer (score 0):

El bucle do while es muy similar al bucle while. su estructura es la siguiente:

```
do {   
    //instruciiones a ejecutar
   }
    while(//condicion para terminar el bucle);
```

La diferencia con el while es simple, el bucle while checa la condicion y en caso de ser "true" ejecuta las intrucciones dentro de su  bloque, a diferencia del do while que lo hace al revez primero ejecuta las instrucciones en el bloque "do" luego comprueba la condicion de bloque "while" y en caso de ser verdadera regresa al bloque "do"

Saludos

Comment: LA diferencia entre los dos radica en que uno asegura que al menos una vez siempre se va a ejecutar el bloque (do..while), mientras que el otro se ejecuta 0 o mas veces (while)

Comment: Correcto @gbianchi, lo que comentas es resultado de que se evalue primero el bloque "do".

Comment: No hay un bloque do.. es una "sola" instruccion. el while pertenece al do.

Comment: @ gbianchi creo que debes de entender mejor los conceptos, una cosa es un bloque y otra muy diferente una instruccion, Te recomiendo que repases estos temas , Saludos